# How to get different data for each widget

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

I'm reading up on `WidgetBundle` and having multiple Widgets - in my case I want to offer the user two different widgets based on gender. So the user can choose to see the *Mens* one and also the *Womens* one.

For each widget the timeline would need to call a different API - what's the best way to do this? I can't see any examples of having a `WidgetBundle` and modifying the timelines to be *slightly* different for each (it's literally a parameter in the api URL). Or is this not possible?

Code:

```
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
// Call API here and get gifts
// I'd want to set "womens" or "mens" in the api url here depending on the widget

    let entry = WidgetTimelineEntry(date: Date(), gifts: gifts, widgetURL: widgetURL)
    let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 30, to: Date())!
    let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: TimelineReloadPolicy.after(date))
    completion(timeline)
}

...

struct WidgetTimelineEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let gifts: [Product]
    let widgetURL: URL
}

struct GiftWidgetEntryView : View {
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) private var widgetFamily
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if widgetFamily == .systemMedium {
                MediumWidgetView(gifts: entry.gifts)
            }
        }
        .widgetURL(entry.widgetURL)
    }
}

@main
struct GiftWidgets: WidgetBundle {
    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {

        // My widgets
        WomensWidget()
        MensWidget()
    }
}

struct WomensWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "WomensWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
        GiftWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
    }
    .configurationDisplayName("Women's Gift Widget")
    .description("See some womens gift ideas")
    }
}

struct MensWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "MensWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
    StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
        GiftWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
    }
    .configurationDisplayName("Men's Gift Widget")
    .description("See some mens gift ideas")
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? a Minimum Reproducible Product would help get better answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @loremipsum Hi I added code. I guess this question is a bit open ended because I can't really find guidance on how you can specify a change in the timeline dependent on which widget it is! I've added an example of how my code is looking :)

Comment: How do you know if the user is a man or a woman or other? You'll need some kind of conditional to identify which to display.

Comment: Also, I would check the guidelines I am sure there will be something about having a gender neutral setting so people are not required to disclose their gender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `gender` parameter to the `Provider` so it can be used later in the `getTimeline` function:

```
enum Gender {
    case male, female // ...
}

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    let gender: Gender

    ...

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        // Configure the API call based on the `gender` property
    
        let entry = WidgetTimelineEntry(date: Date(), gifts: gifts, widgetURL: widgetURL)
        let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 30, to: Date())!
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: TimelineReloadPolicy.after(date))
        completion(timeline)
    }
}
```

Then, you only need to pass the correct parameter to the `Provider`:

```
struct WomensWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "WomensWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider(gender: .female)) { entry in
            GiftWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Women's Gift Widget")
        .description("See some womens gift ideas")
    }
}

struct MensWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "MensWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider(gender: .male)) { entry in
            GiftWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Men's Gift Widget")
        .description("See some mens gift ideas")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a great answer!